# Selecting location co-ordinates based on current location at specific distances

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation, google-maps-api-2

I am building an application in android using eclipse, where i have to choose a set of locations among a collection stored in database based on user's current location and distance at run time and display the co-ordinates on map.

I'm using google map v2 libs.

So basicaly how should i estimate the co-ordinates?
How to retrieve the set of co-ordinates using query?
How to handle the distance of available co-ordinates from user's current location eg. user wants all Hospitals within 1 KM radius.

Any help is appriciated thanks!!!

Comment: See this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10895256/find-items-within-a-certain-range-of-given-coordinate). It might help you.

Comment: its no use Ashish but thanx :)